What is the fastest way to readback a DirectX12 texture on the CPU
I am adding DLSS support to my CPU(yes CPU) path tracer. I couldnt find a fast CPU based implementation.
My pipeline looks like this:

Perform DLSS evaluation
Wait for the GPU to be idle
Read back result on CPU.

Unfortunately number 3 is extremely slow.

Here how I create a readback texture
 D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES const heapProperties =
 {
     /*Type*/                    D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_CUSTOM
     /*CPUPageProperty*/         ,D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_WRITE_BACK
     /*MemoryPoolPreference*/    ,D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_L0
     /*CreationNodeMask*/        ,0
     /*VisibleNodeMask*/         ,0
 };

 auto sharedCmdContext = SharedDx12CommandContextSingleton::instance()->getContext();

 HRESULT hr = sharedCmdContext.device->CreateCommittedResource(
     &heapProperties,
     D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
     &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, m_displayResolution.x, m_displayResolution.y, 1, 1, 1),
     D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
     nullptr,
     IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_readbackHeap)
 );
 ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));


Here how I perform the readback
 //=======================================================================================================
 // COPY DLSS RESULT TO READBACK HEAP
 //=======================================================================================================

 auto sharedCmdContext = SharedDx12CommandContextSingleton::instance()->getContext();

 sharedCmdContext.commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(In_Native_ResolvedColorTexture.buffer, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE));
 sharedCmdContext.commandList->CopyResource(m_readbackHeap, In_Native_ResolvedColorTexture.buffer);

 //=======================================================================================================
 // WAIT FOR GPU TO FINISH
 //=======================================================================================================

 SharedDx12CommandContextSingleton::instance()->endCommandRecording();
 SharedDx12CommandContextSingleton::instance()->finishTasks();

 //=======================================================================================================
 // BUILD FINAL RESULT
 //=======================================================================================================

 // ReadFromSubresource.
 const CD3DX12_BOX iBox(0, 0, m_displayResolution.x, m_displayResolution.y);
 m_readbackHeap->ReadFromSubresource(reinterpret_cast<void*>(resolvedColor->getMutableRawData()), (UINT)resolvedColor->getBytesPerRow(), 0, 0, &iBox);

 // RGBA to RGB. TODO Something faster.
 ASSERT(imageOut.getFormat() == ImageFormat::RGB32F);
 RGB32FImage* imageRGBFOut = dynamic_cast<RGB32FImage*>(&imageOut);
 ASSERT(imageRGBFOut);
 const nbUint32 nbPixels = m_displayResolution.x * m_displayResolution.y;

 tbb::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(nbPixels), [&](size_t tbbIdx) {

     const Uint32 pixelIdx = (Uint32)tbbIdx;
     const Uint32 pixelPosX = (Uint32)(pixelIdx % m_displayResolution.x);
     const Uint32 pixelPosY = (Uint32)(pixelIdx / m_displayResolution.x);
     const Math::Uvec2 pixelPos = Math::Uvec2(pixelPosX, pixelPosY);

     const RGBAFColor pixel = resolvedColor->getPixelFromPosition(pixelPos);
     imageRGBFOut->setPixelFromPosition(RGBFColor(pixel.x, pixel.y, pixel.z), pixelPos);
 });

That readback(ReadFromSubresource) takes up to 300 MILLISECONDs when m_displayResolution is just (1920, 1080).



Please how can I improve performance?
